# EXEC BAD ACCESS Iterating through vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code which is trying to iterate through a vector. It takes as parameters a value, and two iterators: start and end. It is failing specifically on `while (start_iter != end_iter)` throwing a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error code 1.

Here is the code where it blows up:

```
list<int>::iterator const 
find_gt(
    vector<list<int> >::iterator start_iter, 
    vector<list<int> >::iterator end_iter, 
    int value)
{
    while (start_iter != end_iter)
    {
        if (start_iter->front() < value)
        {
            break;
        }
        ++start_iter;
    }
    return start_iter->begin();
}
```

And here is the code that calls it:

```
// Reads a file into the adjacency list
void readfile(string const filename, vector <list<int> > adjList) 
{
    std::ifstream file(filename);
    if (!file.fail())
    {
        string line;
        int i = 0;
        int valueToInsert;
        while (file >> valueToInsert) 
        {
            auto it = find_gt(adjList.begin(), adjList.end(), valueToInsert);
            adjList[i].insert(it, valueToInsert);
            i++;
        }
        file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Could not open file!\n";
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not open file!");
    }
}


int main()
{
    // Vector of integer lists called adjList for adjacency list
    vector <list<int> > adjList;

    // Read the file contents into the adjacency list
    readfile("input.txt", adjList);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at what you're returning. What if `start_iter == adjList.end()`?

Comment: Then it would just return the start_iter (what's wrong with that?). It's blowing up on the actual while line inside the list STL

Comment: No, it will return `start_iter->begin()` which won't work if `start_iter` doesn't point to a valid iterator.

Comment: But it's not even getting to the return statement. Sorry I'm still looking for a solution to this.

Comment: I overlooked a second issue with your code which is that you're doing `adjList[i]` without ever allocating space for a `list<int>` at that position. I think you might want to do `adjList.emplace_back()` as the first line in the while statement in `readFile`.

Comment: Yup that was it. Then I encountered the issue with the second statement after I fixed that. Thanks! All good now. Solved!

Comment: Also your function should take a reference to the vector (`vector<list<int>>& adjList`).

Comment: Yeah I changed that too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function, you return `start_iter->begin()`, even when `start_iter` is equal to `end_iter`.

That is out of bounds access of memory.

Comment: It's not even getting to the return statement so how could it be the return statement? It blows up on the while (start_iter != end_iter) conditional check.